# Why does LocationListener need an internet connection

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I write apps for both Windows Phone in C# and Android in Java.  I have similar apps, on each marketplace, that both use the GPS to track movement as the phone moves about.  When the phone is out moving around, the internet connectivity, of course, goes in and out.

Both versions of my app transmit the GPS readings to my cloud server REST service where they are recorded on to a database.  If the app has no internet connection, it saves the GPS locations on the phone and then, when the internet connection comes back, it bursts what it has to the cloud server.  This process works great in Windows phone.

But with Android, when there is no internet connection, my onLocationChanged event in my LocationListener does not get triggered as the phone moves about.  It's working as though the GPS gets turned off when there is no internet signal.  That makes no sense to me.  Is it supposed to work this  way?  Why would the GPS need an internet connection to work?
Thanks,
Gary

EDIT: We have found from further testing that internet availability has nothing to do with the failure of the onLocationChanged event.  The event simply stops firing in our service after about 20 munutes to a couple of hours for no reason that we can find.

Comment: GPS and onLocationChanged() doesn't use Internet Connection. If you are using Map, then It will use internet connection

Comment: `GPS_PROVIDER` **doesn't need internet connection to work** , you will need internet connection just when you want to transfer the data to your server cloud. i think that you have something wrong in your code, that's all , share your code in order to have more visibility of your problem

Comment: what does the -1 mean??  Can somebody tell me what that means?

Answer (score 0):

No Getting GPS doesn't need internet **necessarily**.

But Getting correct coordinates using GPS in a stable, working and compatible way is a mess.

Often you switch between providers and make use of internet to give good estimates **IF** GPS isn't responding very well.

**Make sure GPS is working and found a nice signal**, because the internet can increase GPS initializing speed.

GPS is really slow to load. It may take 6 to 8 minutes, especially if coverage is poor.  Only after the GPS has actually determined its position. During the first few minutes you won't see anything, since no updates have occurred.

Maybe you use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` in stead of `GPS_PROVIDER`.

Like this

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Try using:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

If internet isn't available.

Try using both, there are plenty of good examples how to make sure you are getting the best possible location. Don;t reïnvent that wheel ;)